# 2N7002P MOSFET N channel complementary P channel

Tags: mosfet, cmos

I want to start creating CMOS logic gates, maybe a binary adder or something, but first I need to know which parts I will be using.

I searched for the cheapest N channel MOSFET, found it (2N7002P), but now I don't know which P channel would fit it the best.

What should I look for? 
What parameters should match? 
Do you guys know any alternatives?
What parameters should be matched?
Here is the link to the 2N7002P: [Clicky](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/nxp-usa-inc/2N7002P,235/568-11588-2-ND/2779619)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CD4007](http://C:%5CDocuments%20and%20Settings%5CSpehro%20Pefhany%5CDesktop%5CStackExchange_and_other_screen_caps%5C2017-01-12%2016_34_23-cd4007ub-1.pdf%20-%20Adobe%20Acrobat%20Pro.png) Dual Complementary Pair Plus Inverter to make CMOS gates at the transistor level.

[image]

The datasheet I linked above has some example circuits. Old CMOS datasheets and databooks often will tell the circuit that is used inside various functions.

Comment: Oh my goodness, that's a trip down a very dusty Memory Lane :-) Good suggestion, fond memories of that IC.

Comment: There also is 74HCU04 ("U" = "unbuffered").

Comment: @CL. Sure, but you can't make transmission gate or a 3-input NOR (for example) with a 74HCU04 because the transistors are committed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no complemantery part for the 2N2007 and even if there was any logic gates you'd make would be quite unusable. I **guarantee** you that you would have a hard time getteing even a simple logic cell to work properly.

Discrete MOS transistors like the 2N2007 have a very large W/L which means only a little bit of Vgs will hugely increase the drain current. That is ideal for switching a relay for example but not for logic gates.

Instead, use the 4000 series or 74xxx series logic ICs. These have easy to use logic gates. Compared to discrete transistors (of which you probably would need  hundreds to make an adder) these ICs are almost no-brainers to use. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400_series) for a description and also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits) for a list of available types.